# Google i/o app: where it sets toolbar_actionbar

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to study the Google i/o 2014's app.

Inside the [BaseActivity](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java) it has this method:

```
protected Toolbar getActionBarToolbar() {
    if (mActionBarToolbar == null) {
        mActionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        if (mActionBarToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mActionBarToolbar);
        }
    }
    return mActionBarToolbar;
}
```

Why findViewById dosen't return null? :/

The content view of the [WelcomeActivity](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/activity_welcome.xml) does this: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);` and this is the activity_welcome.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:iosched="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.WelcomeActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#e5e5e5">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/io2014_logo"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:tint="#7000"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="100dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                iosched:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
                iosched:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
                iosched:cardElevation="@dimen/card_elevation"
                iosched:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="24dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"
                        android:text="@string/welcome_to_google_i_o_app"
                        android:textColor="@color/theme_primary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_xlarge"
                        android:textStyle="@integer/font_textStyle_medium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:text="@string/welcome_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/body_text_2"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:text="@string/eula_legal_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/body_text_2"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>

<!-- Button bar -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/theme_primary"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?photoItemForeground"
        android:text="@string/decline"
        android:textColor="#8fff"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:textStyle="@integer/font_textStyle_medium"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:id="@+id/button_decline" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_accept"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?photoItemForeground"
        android:text="@string/accept"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
        android:textStyle="@integer/font_textStyle_medium"
        android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So it dosen't include in any way the [toolbar_actionbar.xml](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/toolbar_actionbar.xml). Also i looked inside the style.xml for some hint (maybe it was included in all files in some way) but i really can't find anything.

Thanks for help

Comment: from what it seems you would like to implement the toolbar instead of the actionbar right?

Comment: Exactly! @KostasMatrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is going on:

1) `WelcomeActivity` does not extends from `BaseActivity`, so `getActionBarToolbar()` will not be called on this case.

2) `Activities` that are subclasses of `BaseActivity` have `<include layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar" />` somewhere on their view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, Didn't notice that WelcomeActivity dosen't extends BaseActivity. Bytheway, what i asked is where is that include tag? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Look at line 53 of [activity_browse_sessions.xml](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/res/layout/activity_browse_sessions.xml)

Answer (score 0):

They have a layout named https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/toolbar_actionbar.xml

which they < include > in their Activities layouts

Comment: How do they do this? As i said in my question, there is not include tag inside their activity layout.

Comment: Please look at my answer. They do include it on `Activities` that extends from `BaseActivity`

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this guy over [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMO8EVkhJO8). He explains it perfectly.

**Google Documentation:**

http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Here is Google Design Spec you can take a look:

https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: This isn't what i've asked.